# cancel task, if called after shutdown, prevents awaitTermination from returning true

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

Consider this

```
LongAdder count = new LongAdder();
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
var future1 = executor.schedule(count::increment, 1800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
var future2 = executor.schedule(count::increment, 1900, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
//executor.shutdown(); // line 5
System.out.println(future1.cancel(true));
System.out.println(future2.cancel(true));
//executor.purge();
executor.shutdown(); // line 9
executor.awaitTermination(1600, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
System.out.println("isTerminating=" + executor.isTerminated());
System.out.println("terminated=" + executor.isTerminated());
System.out.println("count=" + count.intValue());
```

The program prints isTerminated=true.  But if you call shutdown before cancel (i.e. comment in line 5, comment out line 9), then the program prints isTerminated=false; though if you also call purge (i.e. comment in line 8) then it prints out isTerminated=true.

Is this the expected behavior or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Expected Behaviour:

Scenario 1:  You cancelled the future tasks, then shutdown appropriately, then you awaited termination so you followed the order.  The tasks will cancel, and awaitTermination would succeed as it will finish before it timesout.

Scenario 2:  You shutdown, without cancelling.  In this case awaitingTermination will be false because not all tasks are finished/and/or/cancelled and it will timeout and return false.

Scneario 3:  You shutdown, cancel, purge, awaitTermination.  You actually end up removing all cancelled tasks, and awaitTermination would succeed and isTerminated would return you true as in this case (All tasks are done)

You could also do to see if awaitTermination returns true/false, to see if you actually timed out before the exector had a chance to finish after calling shutdown().

```
System.out.println(executor.awaitTermination(1600, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

Please see the clear documentation on each of these methods and what they do.

**boolean isTerminated()**

> Returns true if all tasks have completed following shut down. Note
> that isTerminated is never true unless either shutdown or shutdownNow
> was called first.
>
> Returns:
> true if all tasks have completed following shut down

Meaning it will only return TRUE if (ALL) scheduled tasks are done, simply calling shutdown will not return true.

**public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout,
TimeUnit unit)
throws InterruptedException**

> Description copied from interface: ExecutorService Blocks until all
> tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the
> timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever
> happens first.
>
> Parameters:
> timeout - the maximum time to wait
> unit - the time unit of the timeout argument Returns:
> true if this executor terminated and false if the timeout elapsed before termination Throws:
> InterruptedException - if interrupted while waiting

**public void purge()**

> Tries to remove from the work queue all Future tasks that have been
> cancelled. This method can be useful as a storage reclamation
> operation, that has no other impact on functionality. Cancelled tasks
> are never executed, but may accumulate in work queues until worker
> threads can actively remove them. Invoking this method instead tries
> to remove them now. However, this method may fail to remove tasks in
> the presence of interference by other threads.